# SQL Server query with condition

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I have four tables.

1. Driver Attendance
2. Driver Information
3. Vechile Detail
4. Booking Detail

I want write a query according the some condition.

Whenever driver will bind then it will bind according vehicle which is assign to driver. and only also that driver will come in Drop Down List which are not Weekly Off, they are not on Leave on the particular date which i will send.

- `tblDriverInformation` column is:  1) id  2) weekly off
- `tblDriverAttendance` column is ---> 1) Driverid 2) Leave From Date 3) Leave To Date
- `Driver Id` is common in above tables.
- `tblVehicle` column is ---> 1) assign to> driver (which is common in above table)  2) id
- `tblBooking` column is ---> 1) Vehicle Id  2) From date with start time 3) End date with time `tblVehicle` and `tblBooking` (in both tables id and Vehicle Id is common Key)

I have prepare a query but it is not giving right but because I am not understanding how to put `tblDriverInformation` and `tblDriverAttendance` condition.

**My query is:**

```
 select 
     A.id, 
     (C.FName + '-' + C.LName) as Car_Driver 
 from 
     tblVehicle A 
 inner join  
     tblDriverInformation C on A.CarId = C.id  
 where
     A.id not in (SELECT VehicleId  
                  FROM tblBooking 
                  join tblVehicle on C.id = A.AssignedDriver 
                  WHERE A.id = @vechileid 
                   and Convert(datetime,@FromDateWithStartTime)  --start date  
                       BETWEEN FromDateWithStartTime AND ToDateWithEndTime  
                    OR Convert(datetime,@ToDateWithEndTime) --endDate  
                       BETWEEN FromDateWithStartTime AND ToDateWithEndTime  
                    or FromDateWithStartTime 
                       BETWEEN Convert(datetime,@FromDateWithStartTime) -- startdate  
                               AND Convert(datetime,@ToDateWithEndTime)  -- enddate  
                    or ToDateWithEndTime 
                       BETWEEN Convert(datetime,@FromDateWithStartTime) -- start date  
                       AND Convert(datetime,@ToDateWithEndTime)   -- enddate
```

Comment: Please clarify your question , what dataset you actually need in query

Answer (score 0):

This might help you out, Below Query Finds out Vehicles and Driver Associated with them with below Conditions.

1- Driver not weekly off.

2- Vehicle available in selected dates (i.e not booked already)

3- Driver available in selected dates (i.e not booked already)

```
SELECT D.ID, V.id
    FROM tblDriverInformation D
    INNER JOIN tblVehicle ON V.DRIVER_ID = D.DRIVER_ID
    INNER JOIN tblDriverAttendance tda ON  tda.DRIVER_ID = D.DRIVER_ID 
    INNER JOIN tblBooking tbl ON V.ID = tbl.VECHILCE_ID 
    WHERE D.WEEKLY_OFF= FALSE -- Driver Not Absent
    AND (@DRIVER_FROM_DATE  NOT BETWEEN (tda.FROMDATE,tda.TODATE) OR @DRIVER_TO_DATE NOT BETWEEN (tda.FROMDATE,tda.TODATE)) -- Driver not absent in these dates
    AND (@VEHILE_FROM_DATE  NOT BETWEEN (tbl.FROMDATE,tbl.TODATE) OR @VEHILE_TO_DATE NOT BETWEEN (tbl.FROMDATE,tbl.TODATE)) -- vehicle not booked in these dates
    -- @DRIVER_FROM_DATE , @DRIVER_TO_DATE, @VEHILE_FROM_DATE, @VEHILE_TO_DATE( user input selected date )
```

Comment: please ask me if you need help or unable to understand anything, would love to help you out!